# Getting Public Facebook Posts with an App Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm using the facebook graph api to access publicly posted information of an arbitrary user. I'm using my own profile for testing and have posted a single public post.

The endpoint that I'm using is:

```
https:graph.facebook.com/v2.4/{id}/feed
```

However, this endpoint returns an empty set of data:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

This occurs regardless of which type of access token I use. I've tried an app access token, a regular access token with no additional permissions, and a regular access token with 'user_posts' selected. I'm especially confused about receiving no data with the last access token as that should include all posts that I've made.

I'd much prefer to use an app access token if possible - it's much easier to get a new one than it is to prompt a user to allow access. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What access token do you need according to the documentation to call user/feed ?

Comment: Please note as per documentation - "Your app needs user_posts permission from the person who created the post or the person tagged in the post. If you attempt to read data from a feed that your app has not been authorized to access, the call will return an empty array."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done for all users. Facebook requires a person to be logged in order to see public posts from certain users. App credentials won't work to see an arbitrary user's public posts.